# Removing white spaces from hyperlinks

Tags: html

I have this problem where as I'm trying to remove white spaces between hyperlinks and cant seem to figure it out.
your help would be much appreciate!

```html
<div class="column full_size">
  <h5>Collaboration</h5>
  Drop us a line on
  <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="blank">Twitter,</a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="blank">Instagram</a> or
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="blank">Facebook!</a>
</div>
```

I need to explain this a bit more. You see the code works it works just as I want to but on the particular site, I'm making a wiki, and its giving me a space in between the hyperlinks, I've tried all that comes to mind but with little to no luck!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Ffo.png
take a look

Comment: can you please give us more clarity. I am not able to see any white space.

Comment: Try putting the markup all on one line instead of separate lines. Some renderers will add a single space to the output whenever the markup goes to the next line in the HTML file (and the next element is not a block-level element).

Comment: What do you mean by [whitespace](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/w/whitspac.htm)?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/cbOXxka.png as you can see there the white spaces between the hyperlinks are a bit too much, I'd like to reduce them

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you trim before passing to HTML if you are using php then you can used PHP trim function or else you can remove in HTML level with the help of Javascript. if you search in google you will get many way how to remove space with the help of javascript ...

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="column full_size">
<h5>Collaboration</h5>
    Drop us a line on
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="blank">Twitter,</a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="blank">Instagram or</a> 
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="blank">Facebook!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: normally you'd not want the "or" as part of the hyperlink. Confusing and looks messy too.

Comment: @Bharat soni could you check what I've edited I'd like to hear your thoughts on it